# call method from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function in controller from directive.

my directive

```
.directive('multEcs', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.addToArray();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Method in controller

```
$scope.addToArray = function(){
    console.log('method called');
}
```

Comment: as you are not using isolate scope.. this should work as is. have you tried it? are you facing any issue? if yes please provide the details

Comment: No errors, but function is not called. The controller is for the whole page which is set on the routes. the directive is inside the page. Is there any issue on that?

Comment: Can you setup plunker

Comment: [http://plnkr.co/edit/6ywb4BcEtbluG4gEGxkm?p=catalogue] I have added just the js file have a look.

Comment: My code worked but only when the method is called from another method inside the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the function you want to call to your directive.

```
 .directive('multEcs', ['$http', function($http){
     return{
         restrict: 'A',
         replace:false,
         scope : {
             myFunctionToCall : '='
         },
         link: function(scope, elem, attr){
             scope.myFunctionToCall();
         }
     }
 }]);
```

Comment: My code worked but only when the method is called from another method inside the directive.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is one-way binding between controller and directive:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('App',[])
.directive('multEcs', [function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            addToArray: '&'                            
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attr){
            $scope.addToArray();
        }
    }
}])
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.addToArray = function(){
        console.log('method called');
    }
}])
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <div mult-ecs add-to-array="addToArray()">multEcs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second way is creating isolated scope in the diretive with personal controller. Recomended for communications between directives:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('App',[])
.directive('multEcs', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.addToArray();
        }
    }
}])
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    this.addToArray = function(){
        console.log('method called');
    };
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div>
         <div mult-ecs>multEcs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code worked but only when the method is called from another method inside the directive.